# What will be the coordinate system of base map layers added if the the coordinate of layer frame properties is MUTM in ArcGIS?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system, arcmap, data-frame

My coordinate frame is in MUTM that I have created. I have added base map layer and I want to know what coordinate system will it use.

Answer (score 0):

As [commented by @Midavalo](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/366684/what-will-be-the-coordinate-system-of-base-map-layers-added-if-the-the-coordinat#comment600225_366684):

> ArcMap will attempt to project the basemap into the coordinate system
> used by your data frame. This can slow the display of the basemap.